# Twitter login throwing OAuthNotAuthorizedException in Android 4.3 and 4.4

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I've integrated twitter in one of my application using Twitter4j, But I am not able to login in `Android 4.3` and `Android 4.4` devices and rest of the other devices it working fine. Following is the code snippet

```
consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer("consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", 
                    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token", 
                    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

oauthUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, "myapp://twitterOauth");
```

and loading oauthUrl in WebView and retrieve the accessToken. It throwing `OAuthNotAuthorizedException.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not doing it already, you have to specify the consumer key and secret that you got from the Twitter API...

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-post-twitter-status-from-android/) which uses [the AndroidTwitter library](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidTwitter), which in turn integrates Twitter4j and the signpost library to access the Twitter API from your app.

Comment: I am using proper Consumer key and Consumer Secret key and its working   fine on Android 4.2 and below.